# Submit Item and Transaction at different times for Google Analytics Ecommerce

Tags: google-analytics

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ecommerce

Using the Google analytics Ecommerce tracking, is it possible, recommended to send Item and Transactions at different times?

Reason being, we do not actually know the revenue amount until a much later time.

Comment: For whatever reason you can't get the revenue amount for a transaction, I believe you could do a data import and upload the cost later. Curiously, though, why won't the revenue be known? How much later would the revenue be available? So as an end user, they won't know the exact amount of their purchase?

Comment: I would like to preface that we are most likely using the google e-commerce feature in an unintended way, with that said, we cannot determine the actual revenue until a much later time (commissions to be paid out are calculated at a later time and are variable). The uploading cost later is a great idea, except could we upload the revenue at a later time? Thank you very much!